# Upload PDF from Python as attachment to Salesforce Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to upload a pdf generated in Python as an attachment to a salesforce object using the simple_salesforce Python package.  I have tried several different ways to accomplish this, but have had no luck so far. Here is the code

```
import base64
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

instance = ''
sessionId = sf.session_id

def pdf_encode(pdf_filename):
    body = open(pdf_filename, 'rb') #open binary file in read mode 
    body = body.read() 
    body = base64.encodebytes(body)

body = pdf_encode('PDF_Report.pdf')


response = requests.post('https://%s.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Attachment/' % instance,
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % sessionId },
    data = json.dumps({
        'ParentId': parent_id,
        'Name': 'test.txt',
        'body': body
    })
)
```

I get this error.

`TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

I have also tried to use

`body = base64.encodebytes(body).decode('ascii')`

in my code, but I can't get that to work either. I get the error

`UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)`

Any suggestions on how to upload a PDF in Python 3 into Salesforce as an attachment using simple_salesforce?

Comment: I don't have an explanation for the error, but I have a similar process working fine via `base64.b64encode(my_file.read()).decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Hi David - thanks for your suggestion.  I tried using that code but got that second error ```UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)```

Comment: .decode("utf-8") was solution for sending my png.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on this and found a few resources to upload files. I created one for myself using that.

Below is the code that you can use for Python and have the file uploaded on Salesforce.

```
import requests
import base64
import json


params = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "Your_Client_Id",
    "client_secret": "Your_Client_Secret",
    "username": "YOUR_EMAIL@procureanalytics.com.pcsandbox", # The email you use to login
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD+YOUR_SECURITY_TOKEN" # Concat your password and your security token
}
r = requests.post("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)
# if you connect to a Sandbox, use test.salesforce.com instead
access_token = r.json().get("access_token")
instance_url = r.json().get("instance_url")
print("Access Token:", access_token)
print("Instance URL", instance_url)

#######################################################################################
# Helper function
#######################################################################################
def sf_api_call(action, parameters = {}, method = 'get', data = {}):
    """
    Helper function to make calls to Salesforce REST API.
    Parameters: action (the URL), URL params, method (get, post or patch), data for POST/PATCH.
    """
    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }
    if method == 'get':
        r = requests.request(method, instance_url+action, headers=headers, params=parameters, timeout=30)
    elif method in ['post', 'patch']:
        r = requests.request(method, instance_url+action, headers=headers, json=data, params=parameters, timeout=10)
    else:
        # other methods not implemented in this example
        raise ValueError('Method should be get or post or patch.')
    print('Debug: API %s call: %s' % (method, r.url) )
    if r.status_code < 300:
        if method=='patch':
            return None
        else:
            return r.json()
    else:
        raise Exception('API error when calling %s : %s' % (r.url, r.content))
        
# Test connection
print(json.dumps(sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/query/', {
    'q': 'SELECT Account.Name, Name, CloseDate from Opportunity where IsClosed = False order by CloseDate ASC LIMIT 1'
}), indent=2))

#######################################################################################
# File Upload from directory
#######################################################################################
# 1) Create a ContentVersion
path = "Folder_name\Sample_pdf.pdf"
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")

ContentVersion = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/ContentVersion', method="post", data={
    'Title': 'Sample_pdf file',
    'PathOnClient': path,
    'VersionData': encoded_string,
})
ContentVersion_id = ContentVersion.get('id')

# 2) Get the ContentDocument id
ContentVersion = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/%s' % ContentVersion_id)
ContentDocument_id = ContentVersion.get('ContentDocumentId')


# 3) Create a ContentDocumentLink
Id = "Abcd123" # This Id can be anything: Account_Id or Lead_Id or Opportunity_Id
ContentDocumentLink = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink', method = 'post', data={
        'ContentDocumentId': ContentDocument_id,
        'LinkedEntityId': Id,
        'ShareType': 'V'
    })
```

---

## How to use

### Step 1:

Key in your email address and password here. Please note that the password here is a string of 'your password' and your 'security token'.

```py
# Import libraries
import requests
import base64
import json

params = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "Your_Client_Id",
    "client_secret": "Your_Client_Secret",
    "username": "YOUR_EMAIL@procureanalytics.com.pcsandbox", # The email you use to login
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD+YOUR_SECURITY_TOKEN" # Concat your password and your security token
}
r = requests.post("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)
# if you connect to a Sandbox, use test.salesforce.com instead
access_token = r.json().get("access_token")
instance_url = r.json().get("instance_url")
print("Access Token:", access_token)
print("Instance URL", instance_url)
```

You can get your security token on Salesforce through **Account  >> Settings >> Reset My Security Token**.
You will receive an email from salesforce with your security token.

### Step 2:

Choose appropriate link for request.post

For **Sandbox** environment:

```py
r = requests.post("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)
```

For **Production** enviroment:

```py
r = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)
```

After your initial connection is ready, the output on the second cell should look something like this:

```py
Access Token: !2864b793dbce2ad32c1ba7d71009ec84.b793dbce2ad32c1ba7d71009ec84
Instance URL https://your_company_name--pcsandbox.my.salesforce.com
```

### Step 3:

Under the 'File upload from a directory' cell (Cell #5), specify your file path.
In my case, this is

```py
# 1) Create a ContentVersion
path = "Folder_name\Sample_pdf.pdf"
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")
```

### Step 4:

Under the same cell, mention the Id in which you would like to upload your file.
The sample code below is uploading a file on Accounts object for an account with Id: *Abcd123*

```py
# 3) Create a ContentDocumentLink
Id = "Abcd123" # This Id can be anything: Account_Id or Lead_Id or Opportunity_Id
ContentDocumentLink = sf_api_call('/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink', method = 'post', data={
        'ContentDocumentId': ContentDocument_id,
        'LinkedEntityId': Id,
        'ShareType': 'V'
    })
```

Comment: .decode("utf-8") part was doin it for me.